# Retorno de Função de Callback

Tags: javascript, callback

Em uma função convencional eu posso retornar um valor e trata-lo fora da função:

```js
var teste;

function funcaoTeste(){
    return 'retorno da funcao teste';
}

teste = funcaoTeste();

console.log(teste);
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: como faço esse mesmo procedimento em uma função de callback e em uma função assíncrona?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não estou bem certo da sua dúvida, mas eu acredito que você deseje buscar o valor de um função assíncrona, vou escrever um código para tenta-lo ajudar, caso não seja o que você procura deixe um comentário para que eu possa ajuda-lo,

vamos criar uma função assíncrona, que retorna um valor depois de 5 segundos:

```js
function espera() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve("finalizado"), 1000 * 5);
    });
}
```

agora vamos fazer uma high-order function que recebe a função espera como callback e aguarda seu retorno:

```js
async function hightOrder(callback) {
    let retorno = await callback();
    console.log(retorno);
}
```

> note que eu optei por utilizar Promisse na primeira função e
>   async/await na segunda, fiz isso com fins didáticos, porém é altamente
>   recomendado que você utilize somente uma das abordagens.

por fim vamos executar a highOrder passando a função assíncrona como callback:

```js
hightOrder(espera);
```

o que esta acontecendo aqui?

A função high-order function chamada hightOrder, recebe o callback chamado espera e a executa, porém aguarda que a mesma seja resolvida, assim que ela for resolvida, imprime no console o seu valor de retorno.

Comment: Muito obrigado por ter respondido! Bom, é basicamente isso mesmo mas ainda tenho uma dúvida: se eu tivesse uma variável do lado de fora dessa função hightOrder, como eu faria pra o resultado ta variavel retorno pra ela?

Comment: simplesmente você pode retornar o valor por exemplo, você teria a variável ```var x = 100;``` fora da função, porém dentro da função você poderia executar ```return x;```, mas é preciso que você note que o retorno dessa função vai ser uma promessa, então será necessário aguardar que ela seja resolvida, com ```await``` ou com Promisse.resolve. 

Sugiro que leia: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Se eu consegui te ajudar, por favor positive meu post.

Comment: Excelente! muito obrigado.